# Why does running sqlclear and syncdb not drop sqlite3 tables

Tags: django, sqlite

I want to drop some tables I created for the `polls` app from the Django tutorials. I am using Django 1.6.5.

I start by turning off the server and then running

```
manage.py sqlclear
```

This prints out

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "polls_choice";
DROP TABLE "polls_poll";

COMMIT;
```

I then run

```
manage.py syncdb
```

When I start the server, go to the admin panel, and click on the models, the values are all still there. Why is this happening? It seems like if I'm dropping those tables, at the very least any existing values should be gone.

Comment: I think you are talking about `sqlclear` and not `sqldump` for the first command.

Comment: oops you're right I was thinking sqlclear but wrote something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlclear), the `manage.py sqlclear` command only **prints** queries to execute to clear the database. You need to execute them by yourself.
You can also use [`manage.py flush`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-flush) to get the empty database (read carefully the documentation, it is actually executing some handlers and adding initial fixtures if you have any)

> #### `django-admin.py sqlclear`
>
> Prints the `DROP TABLE` SQL statements for the given app name(s).
>
> The `--database` option can be used to specify the database for which to print the SQL.

Comment: Hmm I guess I'd have to pipe the output to `dbshell` or something. I thought the `syncdb` was some magic command that executed any "queued" queries, but reading the description for `syncdb` it actually doesn't do much...

Comment: Look at the `flush` command also, it will do what you want ;)

Comment: Tried out `flush`. Looks like a kill switch that resets everything (looking at other questions, it looks like there was something called `manage.py reset`).

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter here:

```
  python manage.py dbshell
```

and paste what sqlclear printed out